# How will jBPM designer 2.4.0 save a BPMN2 file in MySQL(Database configuration)?

Tags: jbpm, drools-guvnor

Actually my requirement is from jBPM designer Web console  will design one workflow(i.e BPMN2 file) and then save into MySQL database so how to set configuration for MySQL?

Note: Without using Drools Guvnor Web console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version are you using? 
If you take a look at version 6.x we implemented a git based backend that store all the assets and index them, I strongly recommend you to use that approach instead of using the Database to store your process files. If you really want to go ahead on that path you will need to implement that logic inside the jbpm designer project. Or you can just export the process xml and store it manually on the DB.